# check file exists not work in laravel on the online host

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to check if a file exists in my host ,but value returns method file_exists() always false in host . this code work in localhost (and returns true)

```
$file_path = storage_path() .'\app\public\image\13.jpg';
if (file_exists($file_path))
{
     return response()
    ->download($file_path, '13.jpg',['Content-Length: '
        . filesize($file_path)]);
}
```

Comment: use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` or `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: You should use the laravel storage functions e.g. `Storage::disk('public')->exists('image/13.jpg')` of course for this to work you need to remember to run `php artisan storage:link` on your server

Comment: Try `$file_path = storage_path('image/13.jpg');` [Laravel Doc: Paths](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#paths)